# React Native - how to disable touchable opacity voice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm trying to create an app and i'm using touchable opacity instead of button.
i just wanna disable voice that on press touchable opacity component.

```
<TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={1} touchSoundDisabled={true} onPress={this._onPress}>
    ...
</TouchableOpacity>
```

i tried to `touchSoundDisabled={true}` but not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Android default "Touchable onPress" sound from react-native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54597558/how-to-disable-android-default-touchable-onpress-sound-from-react-native-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Pressable in place of TouchableOpacity,

Just add `<Pressable android_disableSound={true} ></Pressable>`

one drawback is you cant get onTouch animations, but pressable is powerful

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which version of react native are you using, but I'm guessing what you are looking for is `android_disableSound` prop rather than `touchSoundDisabled`

Comment: version `0.69.5` and `android_disableSound` is not working.

Comment: @ba_rt android_disableSound is for Pressable component